# parallel doesn't show intermediate output to terminal?

Tags: shell-script, parallelism, gnu-parallel

`parallel -k python a1.py {} ::: {0..50..2}`

In the `a1.py`, I have some print statement.

Running the parallel command doesn't show the print statement of my python-script. Is there any way for `parallel` to show the intermediate print command?

Answer (score 2):

`-k` forces GNU Parallel to keep the order, so first you get the output of job 1, and when job 1 finishes, only then do you get job 2.

You can follow job 1's progress with `--linebuffer`:

```
parallel -k --linebuffer python a1.py {} ::: {0..50..2}
```

If you want to follow all jobs' progress, then you cannot keep the order:

```
parallel --linebuffer python a1.py {} ::: {0..50..2}
```